# Cast NSSecureCoding to URL in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, casting, nssecurecoding

I have a `ShareExtension` in which I get the `URL` and I would like to use it but for that I need to `cast` it as a `String`:

```
@objc func actionButtonTapped(){
        print("yeet")
        var html: String?

        if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first,
            itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
                if (url as? URL) != nil {

                    let urlString = String(contentsOf: url)

                    OpenGraphDataDownloader.shared.fetchOGData(urlString: urlString) { result in
                        switch result {
                        case let .success(data, _):
                            // do something
                            print(data.pageTitle!)
                        case let .failure(error, _):
                            // do something
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The code above is throwing this `error`:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSSecureCoding?' to expected argument type 'URL'

**Question:**

How can I cast `NSSecureCoding` to `URL` so I can then cast it as `String` ?? Can't find anything on this anywhere... Happy for every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by first casting it as `NSURL` and then get its `absoluteString` like this:

```
let directoryURL = url as! NSURL

let urlString: String = directoryURL.absoluteString!
```